# Helm Library wrong number of args for include: want 2 got 1

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am trying to implement a Helm library but I am facing an issue it looks like I am not able to solve

Whenever i lint the chart i get this error:

```
**==> Linting .
[INFO] Chart.yaml: icon is recommended
[ERROR] templates/: template: myawesomewebapp/templates/deployment.yaml:4:4: executing "myawesomewebapp/templates/deployment.yaml" at <include "common.deployment" (list . "myawesomewebapp.deployment")>: error calling include: template: myawesomewebapp/charts/common/templates/_deployment.yaml:29:4: executing "common.deployment" at <include "common.util.merge" (append . "common.deployment.tpl")>: error calling include: template: myawesomewebapp/charts/common/templates/_util.tpl:20:22: executing "common.util.merge" at <include (index . 2) $top>: error calling include: template: myawesomewebapp/charts/common/templates/_deployment.yaml:18:10: executing "common.deployment.tpl" at <include>: wrong number of args for include: want 2 got 1**
```

However, it seems to me I am passing two arguments to the merge:

```
{{- define "common.deployment.tpl" -}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  #name: {{ .Release.Name | printf "%s-%s" .Chart.Name }}
  labels:
    test: test
  #{{ include "common.labels" . | nindent 2 }}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  #replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount | default 1 }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      test: test
  #selector:
    #matchLabels:
      #{{ include "common.selectorLabels" | nindent 8 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        test: test
    spec:
      containers:
{{ include "common.container.tpl" . | indent 8 }}
{{- end -}}

{{- define "common.deployment" -}}
{{- include "common.util.merge" (append . {{- define "common.deployment.tpl" -}}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  #name: {{ .Release.Name | printf "%s-%s" .Chart.Name }}
  labels:
    test: test
  #{{ include "common.labels" . | nindent 2 }}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  #replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount | default 1 }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      test: test
  #selector:
    #matchLabels:
      #{{ include "common.selectorLabels" | nindent 8 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        test: test
    spec:
      containers:
{{ include "common.container.tpl" . | indent 8 }}
{{- end -}}

{{- define "common.deployment" -}}
{{- include "common.util.merge" (append . "common.deployment.tpl") -}}
{{- end -}})
```

(comments are there to check if there is a syntax error somewhere)

And this is the merge template :

```
{{- define "debug.var_dump" -}}
{{- . | mustToPrettyJson | printf "\nThe JSON output of the dumped var is: \n%s" | fail }}
{{- end -}}

{{- define "common.util.merge" -}}
{{- $top := first . }}
{{- $overrides := fromYaml (include (index . 1) $top) | default (dict ) -}}
{{- template "debug.var_dump" $overrides }}
{{- $tpl := fromYaml (include (index . 2) $top) | default (dict ) -}}
{{- toYaml (merge $overrides $tpl) }}
{{- end }}
```

Do you have any suggestions to debug this error?

I expect it to merge the two templates correctly

Comment: The call to `common.selectorLabels` is missing its argument; try putting `.` after the template name.  YAML comments `# to end of line` are processed _after_ the Helm templating occurs; consider the `{{/* Go text/template comment syntax */}}` if you need it.

Comment: Thank you David, it seems it fixed the error